# iOS app rejected 'cause not added MFi Product Plan, BUT the accessory manufacturer say they've authorized our app

Tags: app-store, mfi

I'm in big trouble 'cause our iOS app has been rejected by Apple over and over again.
Our app uses a Bluetooth accessory, and I requested its manufacturer to authorize our app and I got the PPID number. I enter that PPID number in the memo for review.

The reply from Apple is as following:
We are unable to post your app to the App Store at this time because your app has not been authorized by the accessory manufacturer to work with the MFi accessory. 
Next Steps/To resolve this issue, please contact the accessory manufacturer to request your app be added to the MFi Product Plan form

- I asked the manufacturer about this problem, and they said they'd registered our app to their PPID and could not guess the possible reason.
- I've got 2 PPID number. I entered both of them - rejected. I entered one by one - both rejected. I entered one PPID number and detailed note(the type, purpose, and so on...) - rejected.

Are there any possible reasons or checklist for this problem?

NOTE. Current app version in App Store is 0.5, and the target version with the accessory is 1.0. I requested the manufacturer with the version 1.0. I do not think it will matter, but does this matter really?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: How about contacting Apple through the resolution center?

Comment: Thank you @LinusGeffarth Sorry for my late response.
I contacted them, but I couldn't get a satisfactory answer.
As I answered, my app was passed suddenly after several re-submission...
From one of the review message, I guess there was an error to check my package name (In fact, it is a little complicated...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you've done everything correctly. You should include both PPIDs in the Review Notes section of the submission (I'm assuming that's where you put them). As long as the app you are trying to submit has a version equal to or greater than the one the manufacturer used, then that shouldn't be an issue.

Double check the Bundle ID, Device Protocol names used by the app, and the app name with the device manufacturer. Those three things must be exactly as the manufacturer submitted them.

Comment: Thank you @person Sorry for my late response.
My app have been approved after several resubmission. Surely I did not changed my information, and there may be an error during the review. From the rejection message, I guess they check the wrong package name ('cause my package name is a little complicated...).